# Is it possible to ignore code to improve loading time?

Tags: jquery, html

I dislike having to load a new page each time I click a link, I'm thinking of building something similar to iframe.

When i click an anchor tag I want to load a div, but I don't want that div content to be loaded before I click that anchor tag.

---

I.e. you go to www.example.com, it loads pretty quick, then you click ‘bio’ or ‘contact us’ and it loads up new content that's already written, kind of telling the browser to ignore parts of the code in the HTML. Is this even possible?

Comment: you're a little late to the party. google "ajax"

Comment: @Anurag - This isn't necessarily AJAX...

Comment: @Noor - Are you talking about loading parts of a page dynamically, requested on demand, or a page with a certain number of links, where different sections are just hidden/shown?

Comment: gotta admit that was funny though, lol

Comment: @Nick - Yep, there are plenty of non-XMLHTTPRequest alternatives. But it seems OP does not know about AJAX which is a rather clean way of doing what (s)he wants.

Comment: @Anurag - Or just showing and hiding some divs, which is simpler and cleaner :) It all depends what they're after, my point was just that it's a bad assumption that it's automatically ajax :)

Comment: @Nick - well I did assume things, you're right about that, but only because the OP said this - "but i dont want that div content to be loaded before i click that anchor tag.". But there are various ways one could interpret that :)

Comment: There are a lot (or a load :) ) of things to do on a site to improve speed (and perceived speed). See Yahoo Yslow! and Google Page Speed and when you'll have optimised your site then it'll be time to consider alternatives to plain ol' pages

Comment: I agree with @Felipe. Remember that you usually want a website that works, even if JavaScript is turned off or simply not available.

Comment: @Nick: Agreed, but the text “I don't want that div content to be loaded before I click that anchor tag” at least implies using something like AJAX.

Comment: Edited to comply with [RFC 2606](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt).

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can type:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#DivName a").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#DivName").load($(this).attr("href"));
        });
    });
    </script>
```

it will work ;)

Comment: if u like to make something like facebook (chat is constant in all pages ) it is called deeplinking u can google it ;)

Comment: I don't think deep linking is what you meant to refer to.

Comment: @Dolph: when i made my own deeplink it was 2 parts first of all set main container from #index which i had done above the second part is url rewrite and reading

Answer (score 0):

I use a product called [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/) to do exactly that. With GWT you will typically change parts of the UI without requesting an entirely new HTML page from the server. You can send requests for data from the server and JavaScript code running in the browser is responsible for displaying that data to the user. GWT applications are written with Java and compiled into JavaScript for execution on the browser. No plugins or extensions are required for your user to run your application, just a modern browser.

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/) is another option. GWT tends to appeal to Java developers because it is written in the Java language, while JQuery is a set of JavaScript libraries that many JavaScript developers are more comfortable with.